# Find the image of the plane $y = x$ (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) under the transformation $T$.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I've been stuck on the following question:

> The transformation $T$ is defined by
> $$T(x, y, z) \;=\; \left(\frac13(2x-2y+z),\; \frac13(x+2y+2x),\; \frac13(2x+y-2z)\right).$$
> Find the image of the plane $y = x$ (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) under the transformation $T$.

I have tried the following:

$$TX = X'$$

$$T^{-1}TX = X'$$

$$X = T^{-1}X'$$

and express $X'$ accordingly:

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \frac13 \begin{bmatrix}2&1&2\\-2&2&1\\1&2&2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\x\\z\end{bmatrix}$

Is this a good approach? Or I have started on the wrong footing?

The answer is: $4x - y + z =0$.

Comment: So you are just asking what would be the equation of the plane in transformed space?

Comment: Yes sorry for the lack of clarification

Comment: Take three points which lie on the plane before transformation, find their transformed coordinate, and then find the equation of that plane, isnt this reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the plane $y=x$ is spanned by $(1,1,0)$ and by $(0,0,1)$, its image under $T$ is the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ spanned by $T(1,1,0)\bigl(=(0,1,1)\bigr)$ and by $T(0,0,1)\left(=\left(\frac13,\frac23,-\frac23\right)\right)$.

Comment: Hi sir. Can you help me reach the answer I have indicated above as I don't quite understand your approach. Thank you.

Comment: Small error: $T(0,0,1) = (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, -\frac{2}{3})$

Comment: @RubenduBurck RIght. Thank you.

Comment: @drew181 No, I cannot. I don't understand your approach. For instance, how do you go from $TX=X'$ to $T^{-1}TX=X'$? Note that both vectors that I get in my answer belong to the plane $4x-y+z=0$, which confirms that that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea seems good, but the details leave a bit to be desired.

If $T(X)=MX$ for some matrix $M$, then we have $X'=MX$. Writing the equation of the plane as $N^TX=0$ and assuming that $M$ is invertible, you can substitute: $$N^T(M^{-1}X') = (N^TM^{-1})X' = (M^{-T}N)^TX = 0,$$ so the vector of coefficients of the transformed equation is $M^{-T}N$. Here, the equation of the plane is $y=x$, which we rewrite as $x-y=0$, therefore $N=(1,-1,0)^T$. I leave the rest of the calculations to you.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am 3 years late but for anyone who is still having difficulties solving this question, all you have to do is randomly choose 3 points on the plane y=x (as hinted y=x coordinates need to be in the form (x,x,y) )and find the transformation under T of the three points (T(x) = X'). Then we use the vector product of the three points AB X AC to find the normal and form the equation of the plane which results in 4x-y+z=0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).