# Linear transformation of a subspace (plane equation)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, canonical-transformation

Consider the linear transformation $T:R^3->R^3$ whose matrix in relation to the canonical basis is:

$[T] = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\0&2&3\\1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

What is the image of transformation $T$ of the subspace $x+y+2z=0$ in $R^3$?

I know the answer should be the equation of a plane, but I cannot come with the correct answer.

Options are:

1. $x+y+2z=0$
2. $3x+2z-3z=0$
3. $-x+y-2z=0$
4. $4x+7y+9z=0$
5. $4x-7y+9z=0$

How should this be solved?

Comment: You can find 2 linearly independent vectors in the plane, find where they transform to, and then use that result to find the transformed plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick three points on the plane, $$x+y+2z=0$$ and transform the points with your matrix. Now find the equation of a plane passing the three transformed points.

I picked three points $$(0,0,0), (1,1,-1),(2,0,-1)$$ and the transformed  points are $$(0,0,0),(4,-1,-1),(3,-3,1)$$ which gives me the plane $$4x+7y+9z=0$$

Thus the correct option is $4$

Comment: I know this is basic stuff but how did you go from your transformed points to the plane equation? An equation system?

Comment: Once you have three points of a plane you  can find the equation of the plane by solving a system. $ax+by+cz=0$ find $a,b,c$ knowing $x,y,z$

Comment: I actually checked my  points against the given options and found option $4$ worked out.

Comment: Checking against the options was a clever move... Because I was pondering that the $(0,0,0)$ point would be problematic if we were to use an equation system.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained recently in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3269285/265466), writing the equation of the plane as $\mathbf n^T\mathbf x = 0$, if you have the point transformation $\mathbf x'=M\mathbf x$, then the transformed equation is $(M^{-T}\mathbf n)^T\mathbf x'=0$. So, apply $M^T$ to each of the coefficient vectors of the potential solutions until you find one that is a multiple of $(1,1,2)^T$. Don’t look for strict equality since both sides of these equations can be multiplied by a nonzero scalar without changing the planes that they represent. You have to allow for this possibility.

Comment: shouldn't it be $M^{-T}$?

Comment: @RegisFontes If you’re asking about how to check the potential solutions, then no: we’re inverting the transformation to go from the transformed equation back to the original one. You could instead compute $M^{-T}\mathbf n$ for the original equation and compare that to each of the potential solutions, but my suggestion avoids having to invert the matrix and will likely be the faster and less error-prone computation if doing it by hand.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the checking of solutions, sorry, should have made it more clear. I got it now, thanks!